# jQuery UI connectToSortable drop event trigger twice

Tags: jquery

I am using jQuery UI draggable and sortable,
When I use `connectToSortable` then drop event get triggered twice.

After searching on net I got that it is a BUG, 
I tried many solution but none of them are working.

Please tell me how do solve `connectToSortable` drop event with and example.

Thanks
I have tried this:

[jQuery UI drop event of droppable fires on sortable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9479438/jquery-ui-drop-event-of-droppable-fires-on-sortable)

[jquery draggable +sortable with custom html on drop event?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8495765/jquery-draggable-sortable-with-custom-html-on-drop-event?rq=1)

Comment: What solutions did you find?  How are they "not working"?  Can you show us the code you've tried?

Comment: Can you provide a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) illustrating the problem?

Comment: `connectWith` do the same issue when drop at other column